# Dealing with deprecation warnings by simply ignoring the warnings

Tags: xcode, pragma, ios15, gcdwebserver

The developers of `gcdwebserver` version 3.5.4 added `#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"` around lines that were causing deprecation warnings in iOS 15.  Specifically, lines having to do with `CC_MD5` and `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` generated warnings before.  I'm concerned that the #pragma lines were added rather than dealing with the actual deprecated code.  Won't Apple eventually remove those deprecated functions?

When it is okay to ignore deprecation warnings (and other warnings) rather than changing the code? What will happen later?

Comment: In general - deprecations are kept around as a stop gap until a future version (which the consumer opts into) removes them. It’s reasonable to ignore the deprecations in the short term, but eventually they’ll need to address them (“Tech Debt”). The deprecations won’t disappear suddenly - they will be part of an update that has breaking changes.

Comment: Specific to iOS app developers - in a future iOS update (hopefully a “major” given that the changes are breaking, as in 16), their app will stop working properly. Apple gives developers time to test out beta versions and catch these kinds of issues before they’re released, and in some cases some apps just don’t fix them in time.